# Are there any Limitations to how much and what can be amended or abolished in the UN charter and ICJ statute

Tags: treaty

It seems like there aren't rules for amendment for ICJ and UN charter beyond a procedure for how they are to be amended. Does the UN or ICJ have a basic structure doctorine or entrenched clause that details what can't be amended ?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the UN or ICJ have a basic structure doctrine or entrenched
> clause that details what can't be amended?

No.

This is mostly because these bodies as such are mostly impotent and so there is not a strong incentive to litigate them or a strong need to amend them. Neither the UN charter or the ICJ have had provisions that have been heavily litigated.

Countries are mostly at peace with the notion that the UN is mostly a talk shop and that the ICJ is mostly a forum in which issues are resolved by mutually consenting sovereign parties.